# "as in" or "as opposite to" in showing dissimilarity?

Tags: comparisons

The usage of "as in" in sentences with negative meaning:

Home dialysis methods have come to the forefront among renal replacement therapies due to the minimal risk of infection transmission as they are performed in an isolated environment at home and due to the **non-**usage of immunosuppressive agents **as in** renal transplant patients.

OR

Home dialysis methods have come to the forefront among renal replacement therapies due to the minimal risk of infection transmission as they are performed in an isolated environment at home and due to the **non-**usage of immunosuppressive agents **as opposite to** the renal transplant patients.

**FACTS:**
**1.** Renal transplant patients use immunosuppressive agents.
**2.** Home dialysis methods does **NOT** use immunosuppressive agents.

Which one of the above two usages (*as in* OR *as opposite to*) is correct? Why?

Comment: Do you have to do so much in one sentence? At least start your sentence with *Compared with transplants*, because then we know what contrast you are setting up. And end with *agents*.

Comment: The question is on the meaning of the sentence in general. A native speaker may handle the situation, I think. (NON-usage and OPPOSITE) or (NON-usage and AS IN). The question is very clear.